# How to know the Database user Login History from begining?

Tags: sql-server-2005, authentication

I need to know one particular user's login and logout database history from beginning in SQL SERVER 2005.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

No, SQL Server does not track successful logins by default. And even if you turn that option, it'll only keep it back through the current log + 6 previous (again, by default), and those logs will be bloated and full of noise. You may wish to implement a logon trigger going forward, but going back in time, this information is simply not available.